# Does cloud sql for postgres beta support dblink?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, dblink

We recently migrated to use hosted gcloud sql for postgres. Am curious to know how i can install dblink because

`CREATE EXTENSION dblink;`

exits with this error,

`ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/share/extension/dblink.control": No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Google CloudSQL does not support dblink yet. Here's the list of supported extensions: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions

We will some more in the upcoming release, but dblink is unfortunately not one of them.

Feel free to [open a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=0) in out [public bugtracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559773) - it will help us prioritize what features to build next.

Comment: Thanks for that, will go ahead and open a feature request.

Comment: I found a feature request here for anyone to "me too" on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62117904